# How do I get more of win7 aero-glass area by decreasing main control container? (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, aero-glass

By default, the form has a limited size title area to which the aero-glass effect is applied. I'd like to increase that area, not only at the title, but at the bottom and the sides of my form.
[image: scheme]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MARGINS {
    int Left;
    int Right;
    int Top;
    int Bottom;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, ref MARGINS pMarInset);
```

Call `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` with your form's `Handle` and a `MARGINS` structure. Just set `Left`, `Right`, `Top` and `Bottom` to the amount you want the respective borders extended by.

Oh, and set the `BackColor` of your form to `Black`. (Thanks, @HansPassant!)

<sub>Sorry if I got the `extern` syntax wrong. I haven't ever done this in C#...</sub>

Comment: Looks like what I'm looking for, but I just can't seem to make it work :x Could you please add a working example?

Comment: It isn't enough, you also have to draw it black: http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Vista-Glass-In-C.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant since you linked to that website, could you please explaing what is `g` in `g.FillRectangle(blackBrush, 0, 0, this.ClientSize.Width, marg.Top);` and how do I use it correctly? Also I see white background instead of described black, is it ok?

Comment: That was a hint to @minitech to help him improve his answer :)

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks, I forgot that part :) Actually, any color except the default will work.

Comment: @user1306322: Just set the `BackColor` of your form to `Black`, it has the same effect. Of course, then you'll want to put a `Panel` with the usual color back over top of it so that everything looks normal.